# ¿Cómo puedo borrar recursivamente directorios si están vacíos?

Tags: java

Bueno, estoy intentado borrar carpetas de un directorio recursivamente:

- Parent directory

  - Carpeta 1

    - Sub carpeta 1
    - Sub carpeta 2
  - Carpeta 2

Se supone que todas esas carpetas están vacías, pues borrarlas todas menos el parent directory.
Como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Propongo que el método en lugar de reportar en texto lo que hace devuelva un `List<File>` de todas las carpetas que fueron eliminadas o de todas las carpetaas que van a ser eliminadas para así tener un mejor control (pruebas unitarias/de integración) sobre el mismo.

El código podría ser como sigue:

```
public List<File> buscaCarpetasVacias(File carpetaRaiz) {
    //siempre retornamos al menos una lista vacía
    List<File> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
    if (carpetaRaiz.isDirectory()) {
        File[] carpetas = carpetaRaiz.listFiles(File::isDirectory);
        for (File carpeta : carpetas) {
            if (carpeta.listFiles().length == 0) {
                resultado.add(carpeta);
            } else {
                resultado.addAll( buscaCarpetasVacias(carpeta) );
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

public void eliminaCarpetasVacias(File carpetaRaiz) {
    List<File> listaCarpetasVacias = buscaCarpetasVacias(carpetaRaiz);
    //de la implementación anterior, sabemos que
    //el método por lo menos retornará una lista vacía
    //no necesitamos hacer una validaciób en caso de nulos
    for (File carpeta : listaCarpetasVacias) {
        //es mejor usar un logger porque así es independiente
        //de la plataforma donde se ejecute este código
        logger.debug(String.format("Borrando la carpeta %s", carpeta.getAbsolutePath()));
        carpeta.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me autorespondo. Con esto, podeis borrar recursivamente todos los directorios y subdirectorios sí estan vacios.

```
public StringBuilder utilsCheckedFilesCorrectly(File[] files, String option) throws IOException {
    String selectedOption = option;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            utilsCheckedFilesCorrectly(file.listFiles(), selectedOption);
            if (file.list().length == 0) {
                file.delete();
            } else {
                sb.append("La carpeta: ").append(file.getName()).append(" no está del todo vacía");
            }
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Hay algunos problemas de código con el método, por ejemplo se pierde el `StringBuilder` que retorna la llamada recursiva de `utilsCheckedFilesCorrectly` y que el método hace 2 cosas en lugar de solo 1: borra carpetas vacías y devuelve un `StringBuilder` indicando un reporte (que en realidad es de la carpeta raíz, no de las subcarpetas) de las carpetas eliminadas.

Comment: Tampoco se entiende qué hace el argumento `option`. Todo método debería documentar claramente que argumentos recibe, qué hace y qué retorna. Otra cosa objetable es que el nombre del método `utilsCheckedFilesCorrectly` no es nada descriptivo

Comment: Entiende que el método esta adaptado a mi programa, puedes hacerlo tipo void

Answer (score 1):

También puedes probar con 
[FileSystemUtils Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileSystemUtils.html)
El ejemplo inferior copia y elimina recursivamente.

Ej:

```
 for(File f : files){
    patherOrigin = FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(filesOrigin.getPath()+"/"+f.getName());
    patherDestination = FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(filesDestination.getPath()+"/"+f.getName());
    ori = new File(patherOrigin);                                           
    desti = new File(patherDestination);
    org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils.copyRecursively(ori, desti);                                           
    boolean delete = org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(ori);
    //XXX hacemos algubna cosa si el tema ha fallado. ??
     if(delete) LOGGER.info("File deleted "+patherOrigin); 
  }
```

[filenameUtils de apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html)

Comment: Puedes crear una instancia de `File` utilizando otro `File` que es la carpeta contenedora, así: `File ori = new File(filesOrigin, f);` y ahorrarte los problemas de separadores de carpetas

Comment: ¡me lo apunto! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay que recordar que no se pueden borrar folders que contienen archivos, por lo que puedes tratar borrando todos en un loop o detectando si están vacíos:

```
File file  = new File("Directorio principal");

    File[] fList = file.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {

if(file.isDirectory()){
        if(file.list().length>0){
            System.out.println("El directorio " + file.getPath() + " no esta vacio!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El directorio " + file.getPath() + " esta vacio!, se procede a borrar.");
            file.delete();
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: No se cubre la eliminación de las sub carpetas tal como pide el OP.